# USB mouse pointer lags when external HD is plugged in

Tags: performance, external-hard-drive, mouse, lag

So I just discovered the cause of my mouse's "random" lagging. I have a Microsoft 3500 USB mouse and a Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex 500 GB external hard drive. When the former is plugged in, everything is fine. But when both of them are plugged in, the mouse pointer slows down and lags a lot (or jerks).

All my drivers are up to date and I'm on Win 8.

Any possible diagnostics/solutions?

Comment: Does this persist for as long as the drive is plugged in, or for a while and then stops? Where are they plugged in? On a laptop, dock, desktop? Which ports? Same hub?

Comment: Yes it persists for as long as both the devices are plugged in. It's a laptop (Dell XPS 15z). USB ports.

Comment: Does your HDD have an external power supply?

Comment: No it does not....

Answer (score 8):

sounds like the external hdd is either drawing to much amperage from usb, or the data transfer of the drive is keeping the usb hub too busy for the mouse to get its data processed in a timely manner.

Try using the external hdd on opposite sides of the laptop if possible by laptop design.

Does this happen with normal usb flash drives? if not does it happen while moving a large file to flash drive? if yes then its the usb hub going out. if no then you can move to the external hdd next.

does the external hdd produce the same result on another pc, (plug same mouse and external hdd into two closest usb ports on another machine and test) if the same results happens here then it is definitely the the external hdd. you could try taking the hdd out of the case and just plug it into a desktop pc to see if it is the drive that is malfunctioning or the external case enclosure.

If it is the external enclosure that is bad you may be able to get a replacement from the manufacture or buy a third party from http://www.newegg.com or http://www.ebay.com

If the result is that your usb hub is going out, do you have a pcmcia slot on your pc. you can get a usb 2.0 possibly a 3.0 adapter card that would eliminate this problem

Comment: some usb hubs on laptops are replaceable, some are part of the mainboard. find your service manual to find out in detail. (or just open it and look :)

Comment: Using the external hdd on opposite sides of the laptop, works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this behavior on all of my (Quad-Core i7) laptops, with a variety of Logitech mouse/keyboard sets, and different USB sticks and external drives.

This solution worked for me on Windows 10:

- Open "Control Panel"
- Select "Power Options"
- Select "Change plan settings"
- Select "Change advanced power settings"
- Expand the "USB settings", then "USB selective suspend setting"
- Change the two options to "Disabled"

[image: Set these to Disabled]

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem with my MacBook Pro retina .USB 3.0 externalnal hard drive use 5 GHZ and  cause lag 2.4 GHz mouse lag, buy a 5G mouse (Rapoo have) and put directly usb 3.0 port (do not use hub) and use your mouse and usb 3.0 external harddrive together lag free

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with desktop system. First thing I thought of was possible "radio frequency" inteference with USB wireless receiver? My solution, moved external hard drive (EHD) to other side of desk / table via USB cable extender & plugged EHD into a power point / wall socket away from computer case. This solution fixed "severe lag / unresponsiveness" in wireless keyboard also caused by initial plugging in of EHD. I'm not sure if the power point / wall socket thing made any difference. It was just convenient to do so once I'd moved EHD.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue this is what worked for me after some research on the internet:

"Move your USB 3 or Thunderbolt 3 devices—including any USB hubs—farther away from your wireless devices."
-https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201542
(Originally ere:https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/installed-external-ssd-and-my-mouse-is-now-lagging.2016801/)

From my own experience you need to move the wireless device(the USB receiver) away from the USB 3 ports on motherboard, by using an extension cable, hub, or similar accessory. Some monitors or keyboards or wat els also have built-in USB hub.

Why the down vote? It is a validated solution ye twa